# Installing the right manpages for the Xenial HWE stack

Tags: 16.04, manpage, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm on 16.04 with the HWE-stack enabled, meaning kernel 4.10 (`4.10.0-37-generic` specifically).

However, my man pages package is still suck at 4.04:

```
dpkg --list manpages
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                            Version              Architecture         Description
+++-===============================-====================-====================-====================================================================
ii  manpages                        4.04-2               all                  Manual pages about using a GNU/Linux system
```

These man pages are out of date with respect to my kernel and I've already run into an issue once. The same applies to the `manpages-dev` package.

Is there any way to get `manpages` version 4.10 on my box?

Comment: The `manpages` package and the kernel version are independent. The version on 14.04, for example, was 3.53, and there's certainly no Linux kernel with that version number. Post your actual issue, please.

Comment: Huh, we'll that's quite the coincidence then. It seems to me that the [manpages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/changelog.html) does align the version number with the kernel. For example, kernel 4.13 has been released, and the last version of the manpages project is 4.13. The default kernel for Xenial is 4.04 and the manpages version is 4.04. Artful is  going to release with kernel 4.13 and manpages 4.13. So it beggars belief that the numbers are unrelated. My actual problem is that I'd like the updated `manpages-dev` package, 4.10 ideally, but 4.09 or 4.13 would be OK too. @muru

Comment: The kernel version is 4.4, not 4.04. The releases might be in sync, but unless Linux released a version 3 in 2008, it doesn't look like that coincidence extends much into the version history. Anyway, since the `manpages{,-dev}` packages don't depend on anything else, you could simply grab a newer release's packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com and install them.

Comment: Sorry, you are right - the  kernel is 4.4 but it seems that the manpages project always puts a leading 0 for 1 digit secondary version numbers.  I'm not sure how the older versioning worked, but it seems they are synced now. Is there a way to install a newer version from `apt-get`? Thanks for the tup.

Comment: See https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/

Comment: Following the link from @chaskes it seems to me the simplest way to get a different version of manpages is to `git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages; cd man-pages; git checkout man-pages-4.10; MANPATH=. man ...`